# How do I convert a Word doc to HTML and load it as a local file in WKWebView?

Tags: html, ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

The Word doc has been converted to HTML using: https://word2cleanhtml.com/cleanit

Here is a sample of the HTML generated (perhaps the problem is here because I know next to nothing about HTML):

```
<p dir="ltr">
    TERMS AND CONDITIONS
</p>
<p dir="ltr">
    Last updated: 2020-06-01
</p>
<p dir="ltr">
    1. Introduction
</p>
<p dir="ltr">
    Welcome to MyCompany (“Company”, “we”, “our”, “us”)!
</p>
<p dir="ltr">
    These Terms of Service (“Terms”, “Terms of Service”) govern your use of our
    mobile application (individually herein after referred also as “Service”)
    operated by MyCompany.
</p>
```

And then I load this into a `WKWebView` in a view controller like this:

```
import WebKit

class Terms: UIViewController {
    
    let termsWebView: WKWebView = {
        let webview = WKWebView()
        webview.backgroundColor = .white
        return webview
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view = termsWebView
        loadTermsHTML()
    }
    
    func loadTermsHTML() {
        
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "tnc", ofType: "html") else { return }
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) {
            let termsString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            termsWebView.loadHTMLString(termsString! as String, baseURL: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that while the HTML is loaded, it's not rendering based on the formatting. I just see the exact same content with the markup language in the HTML file that I added into the project directory.

Comment: does your file include `<html><body>...</body></html>` tags?

Comment: no, it doesn't. The snippet I included above is literally the beginning of the file.

Comment: Actually nevermind, I tried your code and it works: generates a proper view for me in playground. So the only problem I can think about is that you have some invisible characters in your HTML file, which cause the string to not be considered as valid HTML... Also you don't need `NSString` here, you can use a much shorter `let termsString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)` (but that doesn't affect the result either way)

Comment: I suggest this: take the HTML you posted here from this post, and put it in your file. See if it works. If it does - the problem is with content of the file.

Comment: You were right. It's the missing html and body tags. If you answer the question, I'll mark it as correct because that's how I arrived at the solution.